# The instance of entity type ... cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Given an ASP.NET Core webapp using Entity Framework Core and an SQL database.

An absolute simple action is throwing this exception when trying to update an entity in the database. First noticed by a bug report in production.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("Group")] EditViewModel model)
{
    if (id != model.Group.Id) return NotFound();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

    _context.Update(model.Group);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Exception is thrown at the line: `_context.Update(model.Group);`

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Group' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Clearly there is no other instance. I was able to reproduce the exception in my development environment when I stopped the code with a breakpoint on that line and expanded the Results property of the `_context.Group` object:
[image: screenshot of expanded Results property of the _context.Group object]
It's understandable, that when expanding the Results, it loads the instance needed to be updated and that's why the exception is thrown. But what's about the deployed production environment?

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE1** `Group` model:

```
public class Group
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE2** Based on @Mithgroth's answer, I was able to override the function `_context.Update()` to not need try-catch every time I use it:

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    }

    try
    {
        return base.Update(entity);
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
    {
        var originalEntity = Find(entity.GetType(), ((IEntity)entity).Id);
        Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        return Entry((TEntity)originalEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: These are all lazy loaded sets. When you expand `_context.Group`, Entity Framework is querying the store and populating the in-memory context with entities. When you then attempt to attached non-tracked entity `model.Group` in your call to `Update`, it will attempt to attach this foreign instance and will then find a collision with the already existing entity (which I presume exists in the backing store (the DB)). Are you re-using an Entity Framework context instance between requests?

Comment: You should not be receiving Entities in a Controller. You should use ViewModels and either map them manually or use a mapper library to translate between ViewModel and Entity.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the `_context` variable, i.e. when is created and when disposed? You can check the tracked entities by expanding `_context.Group.Local` property.

Comment: Hi @odyss-jii, yes, that's clear, but that's only when I'm debugging and expanding the results - enumerating it. But why does the problem exists in release - production? There should be no enumeration or breakpoint.
And yes, I'm reusing the DbContext as far as I know: `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Hmm, `AddDbContext<..>` should be creating scoped context per request, so your code should work. If you can reproduce it in dev environment (w/o expanding the `DbSet` which loads the whole table), put a breakpoint and check if `_context.Group.Local.Count` property is `0`. Also what does `model.Group` contain. And btw, can we see the `Group` entity model (class), specifically navigation properties (any chance to contain other `Group` objects?)

Comment: Can you please try the following: `var group = db.Groups.First(g => g.Id == model.Group.Id); db.Entry(group).CurrentValues.SetValues(model.Group); db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @IvanStoev I was not able to repro the bug in dev env, but occured in prod.
The model object is a ViewModel and contains a `Group Group` and a `SelectList CountryList`. 
I have updated the question with the Group class.

Comment: @Mithgroth this works!! But IMHO `_context.Update()` still shouldn't produce this exception in prod environment. Or should I override `Update()` function with this method because the default isn't safe?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
var group = _context.Group.First(g => g.Id == model.Group.Id);
_context.Entry(group).CurrentValues.SetValues(model.Group); 
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The exception can be caused by many different scenarios but the thing is, you are trying to change the state of an object which is already marked differently.

For instance, this would produce the same exception:

```
var group = new Group() { Id = model.Id, ... };
db.Update(group);
```

Or you might have detached N-tier children, that's all possible.

This ensures that you are just overwriting an existing entity's values.

Comment: Great, thank you Mithgroth! My only question is, that as I see in this case there is nothing that can cause the original object to change, so what assures me that in other controllers the `Update()` function won't fail with the same? Do I need to change them all? Or can I override the whole `_context.Update()` function? Thanks!

Comment: I can't say for sure but I learned this the hard way too. You might roll a try catch and fallback to this style if you want to. Or you can go all the way in with this since I've seen no side effects of doing `CurrentValues.SetValues()` yet. It just feels a bit awkward than just calling `Update`. Anyone is welcome to explain in a more sophisticated manner than mine :)

Comment: OK, thank you @Mithgroth! By the way, I was able to override the `_context.Update()` function, please see **UPDATE2** at the end of the original question.

Comment: only working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the ideas.
I made this overridden function on my context working without Exception, which is imho a slightly better approach. Also, the primary key name is retrieved using the defined model.

Also, it is EntityFramework 3.0 .NET Core

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using System.Linq;



    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        }

        var type = entity.GetType();
        var et = this.Model.FindEntityType(type);
        var key = et.FindPrimaryKey();

        var keys = new object[key.Properties.Count];
        var x = 0;
        foreach(var keyName in key.Properties)
        {
            var keyProperty = type.GetProperty(keyName.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            keys[x++] = keyProperty.GetValue(entity);
        }

        var originalEntity = Find(type, keys);
        if (Entry(originalEntity).State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            return base.Update(entity);
        }

        Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        return Entry((TEntity)originalEntity);
    }
```